# Mathematica CForm / FortranForm bug?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to output a very complicated matrix (~1.3MB in plain text) from Mathematica to use in a Fortran program. When I do this (via `Splice`) the resulting matrix is off by ~2% when numerical values are given to the variables. This is a problem since there needs to be an eigenvalue that is exactly zero, and the composition of the eigenvectors needs to be exactly correct.

I've done all the usual due diligence regarding precision, correct variables, proper diagonalization code, etc. and It came down to either Fortran itself being unable to cope with such a large matrix or Mathematica messing up the FortranForm output.

So I made Mathematica give me the CForm of the matrix and tried that. It was also ~2% off from what it should be, more astoundingly, it was the same (within machine precision) as the FortranForm matrix!

Has anyone come into contact with this kind of problem? Do you have any idea what might cause it? I dread the need to go through 25000 lines of Mathematica formatted Fortran code to figure this one out.

EDIT: The matrix in question is complicated, not large. It is only 6x6 but each element is individually algebraically very messy including trigonometric functions, logarithms, and various roots and powers.

The [Plaintext](http://pastebin.com/wYyemZUN) of the (1,1) element of our matrix, the [C code](http://pastebin.com/tu7tEmJE), and the [Fortran code](http://pastebin.com/r5Vw2U5b). Sane parameter values are: 0 < lambda, kappa, Y*** < 1; all others between 100 and 1000.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the error in a smaller matrix ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that it is a symbolic matrix that you export? And that when you evaluate it in Fortran/C and import the numerical result to Mathematica, the entries are off by 2% relative to evaluating the symbolic expression in Mathematica?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: No, we did testing with much simpler matrices and they all are reproduced within machine precision.

Comment: @Janus: Yep, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: 1.3 MB for a 6x6 matrix ? Array[myGuinnessRecord[... :D

Comment: If it is only 6x6 could you post the matrix? If not the whole matrix, a single element that is off would be illuminating I think.

Comment: I posted the (1,1) element for your pleasure and perusal. Now it will be thoroughly embarrassing if you manage to get the values to coincide in all three cases (even though it would probably be helpful in figuring out what we are doing wrong ;-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the expressions for the first element, this is almost certainty a problem because of finite precision floating point arithmetic. It seems to me there are two ways to try and approach this problem. The first is to use more precision in the C code. Perhaps you could use the macro pre-processor (or just find and replace) to change all of the declarations in the C code from double to long double. Depending on what compiler you are using that will get you from 64 bits to 80 or 128 (unless you use [Microsoft's compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) which treats long doubles as standard doubles). If you post what C compiler you are using I could help look at what changes you would need to make to go that route. At the very end you can cast down to a double if you need to pass it to Mathematica or another C program that is just using doubles.

Also, C compilers can have different floating point modes. Might be worth checking whether the mode is set for precise, strict or fast. If it is on fast or fast-math then that might be contributing to your rounding problems.

The other route is to use Mathematica to rearrange the terms of each element to optimize for floating point accuracy. While in general (a*b)*c=(c*b)*a in the land of floating point arithmetic this isn't true. The best heuristic I have heard of is:

1. Addition: add the terms from smallest to largest to minimize rounding errors
2. Subtraction: avoid or delay subtracting values that are very close to each other in value so you maintain as many significant digits as possible
3. Multiplication/Division: avoid/delay multiplying by very small numbers or dividing by very large numbers for reasons of significant digits again.

In practical terms this means factoring these expressions is your best bet, especially problematic terms. if a1~=a2 then the expression (a1-a2)(b-d) should have more accuracy/significant digits than (a1-a2)*b-(a1-a2)*d because you have one less multiply operation.

Comment: Although it was a pain in the but, refactoring the expression helped.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the following simple thing: Mathematica is quite clever about numerical evaluation, so for example these two expressions

```
N[(10^18+100)-10^18]
N[10^18+100]-N[10^18]
```

resul in quite different output

```
Out[3]= 100.
Out[4]= 128.
```

With C or Fortran you don't get any babysitting and the expression would be evaluated as in the second line.
Maybe you could look at a single matrix entry and try to evaluate it in Mathematica as C/Fortran would, and see if this matches what you see?

EDIT:
It seems that a simple test for problems with intermediate precision is to use `Compile` which drops all precision checks, so that

```
In[10]:= Compile[{a,b},a+100-b][10^18,10^18]
Out[10]= 128.
```

Could you check whether a compiled version of your matrix agrees with C/Fortran?

Comment: The elements of our matrix are O(10^6) at most and individual variables are O(1)--O(1000) so well within single precision and certainly within double precision which is what we use in Fortran. Also, we artificially reduced Mathematica's precision to 4 digits and still got within 0.01% of the original result.

Comment: Well, that you get less than 10^-4 error with N[expr,4] is exactly what the box says: If I understand things correctly, N[,k] guarantees the result to be correct to k digits precision. I can certainly think of some situations where even a lot more working precision would get you less accuracy than N[,4].

Comment: @Timo: After trying all kinds of clever code to make Mathematica stupid, I realized that Compile is the simply way to test whether intermediate precision is your problem. See edit above.

Comment: Yeah, well Mathematica is not being stupid as such, we just wanted to see if a low precision evaluation of the matrix elements (and we try evaluating single elements, though they are themselves very large) will reproduce the error that both Fortran and C produce. Since the errors Fortran and C produce are identical, independent of machine architecture, nor reproducible by lowering precision in Mathematica, we conclude that the only common element left is that Mathematica produces somehow buggy code, but with the exact same error on C and Fortran. Sounds ludicrous, hence me asking SO for help.

Comment: @Janus, what you're showing is a problem with all finite precision arithmetic.  For instance, on a 10 digit calculator try 1E12 + 1 - 1E12, and for any order but having the 1 out front will give zero for the result.

Comment: @rcollyer exactly: The point I am trying to make is that C and Fortran are in effect 16 digit calculators, which might very well be why their answers agree. On the other hand, `N[expr, 16]` is not a 16 digits calculator, but rather a clever algorithm that will use up to `$MaxExtraPrecision` extra digits to get 16 digit precision in the result (and hopefully do other clever things).

Comment: @Janus, you might be right with `N`. `$MaxExtraPrecision`, however, only works inside of `N`. So, if you change your code to `10.^18 + 100. -10.^18` you'll get the exact same behavior as if you were using a calculator.  (Note, the decimal points.)